# Integer has incremental value in Excel... how?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

So, I'm making a thing for my work whereby I need to work out a total value based on an unit value which increases after X-number of units. Basically;
0-49 is worth A
50-59 is worth B
60-69 is worth C etc etc.

I need to read the quantity from one cell and multiply by the increments to give a total value

For example, if "Quantity" cell = 65 units
I need to work out (49*A)+(10*B)+(6*C), etc.

It's been a while since I've used Excel and formulae, so I'm rusty and this and can't find anything online (mostly because I can't think of the right way to word what I mean).

Any suggestions?

Comment: so if a customer bought 55, 49 would be at price A per unit and 6 at price B per unit?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it (wasn't sure if I was making it clear or not haha)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a table with the starting numbers, the span and the amount:

[image]

Then use this formula that refers to that table

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT($D$1:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A1,C:C)-1),$E$1:INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A1,C:C)-1)),0)+(A1 - VLOOKUP(A1,C:C,1,TRUE)+1)*VLOOKUP(A1,C:E,3)
```

[image]

This method has the benefit that one can add to the search table and not change the formula.  The formula is the same if there are 50 lines in the lookup table or 2.

Comment: You, my friend, are a goddamned GENIUS!! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I've had a play around with it there to get an understanding. I cannot repay you enough for your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is awesome, thank you a thousand times over. Is there anyway I can give a "like" or "karma" or some kind of approval for your help?

Comment: @IanScott glad to help, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your quantity is Q (a cell reference such as A1) and the prices are A,B and C (either numbers or cell references).  Then the total price is

```
=IF(Q<50,A*Q,IF(Q<60,49*A+(Q-49)*B,IF(Q<70,49*A+10*B+(Q-59)*C)))
```

If there are more price points (D,E, etc.) then the pattern in the formula continues:

```
...IF(Q<80,49*A+10*(B+C)+(Q-69)*D,IF(Q<90,49*A+10*(B+C+D)+(Q-79)*E)))))
```